# PDO PHP error al insertar un registro usando $_SESSION como parametro

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy tratando de insertar un registro a una tabla en phpmyadmin, pero estoy tratando de usar $_SESSION['RAMA'] ya sea admin, empleado, etc. El punto es reducir el tabajo para no hacer archivos de script para cada tipo de usuario

El error que me salta es el siguiente:

```
Error!: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''Admin' (codigo_es, Nombre, Celular, Email, insignias, imagen_es, id_registro_' at line 1
```

Tendrán alguna sugerencia?
Anexo el código

```
public function create() {

    try {

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO :rama (codigo_es, Nombre, Celular, Email, insignias, imagen_es, id_registro_general)  VALUES (:codigo_es, :Nombre, :Celular, :Email, :insignias, :imagen_es, :id_registro_general)';

        $data = [
            
            'rama' => $_SESSION['RAMA'],
            
            'codigo_es' => $this->_rollNo,

            'Nombre' => $this->_name,
            
            'Celular' => $this->_className,

            'Email' => $this->_email,

            'insignias' => $this->_Insignia,
            
            'imagen_es' => $this->_image,

            'id_registro_general' => $this->_Id_Registro,


        ];

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute($data);

        $status = $this->db->lastInsertId();

        return $status;



    } catch (Exception $err) {

        die("Error!: ".$err);

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes usar marcadores para nombres de tablas o columnas, como haces aquí:

```
INSERT INTO :rama ...
```

Si la intención ahí es sustituir `:rama` por un nombre dinámico debes asignar el nombre desde la variable que lo contenga, no en forma de marcador.

Por ejemplo:

```
public function create() {   
    try {    
        $rama=$_SESSION['RAMA'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $rama 
                  (
                    codigo_es, 
                    Nombre, 
                    Celular, 
                    Email, 
                    insignias, 
                    imagen_es, 
                    id_registro_general
                   )  VALUES (
                    :codigo_es, 
                    :Nombre, 
                    :Celular, 
                    :Email, 
                    :insignias, 
                    :imagen_es, 
                    :id_registro_general
                   )";
        $data = [
            ':codigo_es' => $this->_rollNo,
            ':Nombre' => $this->_name,
            ':Celular' => $this->_className,
            ':Email' => $this->_email,
            ':insignias' => $this->_Insignia,         
            ':imagen_es' => $this->_image,
            ':id_registro_general' => $this->_Id_Registro,
        ];  
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);    
        $stmt->execute($data);    
        $status = $this->db->lastInsertId();    
        return $status;    
    } catch (Exception $err) {
        die("Error!: ".$err);
    }
}
```

Comment: en la variable $sql, como concateno $rama?, asi como lo pones, me marca error

Comment: @karlDomínguez ¿qué error marca? Debes asegurarte de que en la variable de sesión hay un nombre válido. ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($rama);`?

Comment: Gracias, ya se resolvió :D